# Extracting chunks from corrupt region files

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I recently made a boo-boo and lost my entire save file along with all backups. I was able to recover my save using a file recovery tool but the regions where all of my buildings are do not load either in game or in MCEdit and when I try to open the file with NBTExplorer it says "Not a valid region file".

Since my buildings only cover maybe a dozen chunks or so, I'm hoping there's a way to read the region file maybe as a text format to just pull out the chunks with my buildings in and transplant them into a new save.

Does anyone know of a way to read the .mca region files, perhaps as text, and extract the chunks I'm interested in to put them into a new save?

Comment: You could try [this tool](https://github.com/HubTou/MCA2NBT). But if NBTExplorer already can't read it, I'm not too optimistic.

Comment: @FabianRöling I did look at that, but I'm not sure it would work since it can't bring the chunks back together. My assumption was that NBTExplorer was trying to read the entire file and failing so my thought was to try and read it incrementally or try and put it back together if I can see it in a text form.

Comment: It's not saved as text, so you would need a special program made exactly for reading corrupted NBT files. There might be one, I don't know.